# How to get when comma "," is entered in Edit text in android

Tags: android, android-edittext

How would I get that when Comma "," is entered in Edit text.
Here what I am doing

```
newCategryET.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence returnedResult, int start,
                int before, int count) {

            String result = returnedResult.toString();
            String result2 = result.substring(result.length() - 2,
                    result.length() - 1);
            if (result2.equals(",")) {
                addCategoryToLayout(result.substring(0, result.length() - 1));
                newCategryET.setText("");
                return;

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
```

I want to add the text of my Edit text to a layout whenever Comma is pressed
But I am getting array index out of bound exception.

Any Help

Here is my logcat error -

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; regionStart=-1; regionLength=1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the string's contains method to check that the string contains comma or not

```
String.contains(",")
```

and then you use string tokenizer to split the string whenever the comma appears

Answer (score 2):

Consider the case when the very first character is entered (as q):

- Result evaluates to  'Q'
- Result.Length() evaluates to 1
- Result.substring(result.length() - 2,result.length() - 1) evaluates to Result.substring(-1,0)

Trying to take this subtsring starting at position -1 causes your exception.

There are several easier solutions to this problem - such as checking String.contains(",") or String.IndexOf()

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence returnedResult, int start, int before, int count)
{
    String result = returnedResult.toString();
    if(result.length() == 0) return;
    //if(result.contains(",")) // another method
    if(result.charAt(result.length() - 1).equals(",") // last character is ','
    {
        // comma is entered
        addCategoryToLayout(result.substring(0, result.length() - 1));
        newCategryET.setText("");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way, hope this will work

```
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence returnedResult, int start,
                    int before, int count) {

                    if (count > 0) {                    

                    String s1 = "" + result.charAt(start);
                    if (s1.toString().equals(",")) {
                        addCategoryToLayout(result.substring(0, result.length() - 1));
                    newCategryET.setText("");
                    return;
                    }
                }
            }
```